# What does Crystal Reports use when a numeric field is set to System Default Number Format?

Tags: crystal-reports, number-formatting

I have a customer that is getting a Divide by Zero error when running a standard report, even though there are no formulas in the report that divide by anything.  When I changed the format of one of the numeric fields in the report from System Default Number Format to "-1,123.00" the error went away.  Why would that be?

Comment: There must be something using that numeric field as a divisor somewhere.  Are you able to run the report in the Crystal Reports designer?  When a divide by zero error occurs in the designer, it should open the formula editor for the formula where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks, but the data source is a .csv file, and the customer has CR 2020, which doesn't allow the use of text files as data sources, so I can't preview it.  I tried it locally, with CR 2016, but didn't get the error.  There are no formulas that use division in the report.

Comment: If you are 100% positive there are no formulas using division, I would recommend contacting SAP support for this because it may be a bug.  The divide by zero error is a very specific error that should not be encountered if you are not using division in a formula somewhere.

Comment: I did have one other idea that might he worth trying.  Would it be possible to import that CSV file into an Access database or other DBMS that you would be able to connect to from CR 2020 using ADO or ODBC?